# How to get the positions of array duplicates JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, loops, nested

I currently have this code:

```
String foxes = "The,Quick,Brown,Fox,Jumped,Over,The,Lazy,Dog.";
    System.out.println(" Here is the string unedited: " + foxes);
    String lowerCase = foxes.toLowerCase() .replaceAll("[\.:;'\"!\?]", " ");
    System.out.println(" Here is the string (no caps + no punctuation): " + lowerCase);

    List<String> foxesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(lowerCase.split(",")));
```

In short this code creates a `String`, makes it non case sensitive and then converts it into an array.

I now need to find the positions of each of the duplicates in the array and I currently am aware that it has something to do with nested loops. The duplicates are The which occurs 2 times. I need to know the positions of these 2 duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `HashMap<String, int[]`:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < foxesList.size(); i++) {
    String fox = foxesList.get(i);
    ArrayList<Integer> list = map.get(fox);
    if (list == null) {
        list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(i);
        map.put(fox, list);
    } else {
        list.add(i);
    }
}
```

In this map for each fox name, you'll store all indexes of this fox. In case the list has more then one element, it means there is a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, for others who want to know what to print it is simply map and then you are given the answer. Props to you, this code really helped :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
HashMap(key: String, value: ArrayList)
```

to store the strings

where arraylist will store the corresponding indexes.

If `value.size() > 1`, it's keys occurrence > 1.

Code :

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> dictMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    String strArr[]={"Hi", "Foo", "Bar", "Foo"};
    for(int i = 0; i < strArr.length; i++){
        String  str = strArr[i];
        if(dictMap.containsKey(str)){
            ArrayList<Integer> al = dictMap.get(str);
            al.add(i);
        }
        else{
            ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            al.add(i);
            dictMap.put(str, al);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry I don't fully understand what you mean by this, can you give an example?

Comment: insertion code is added. Have a look. Next, you need to traverse and check each map entries to see if arraylist size > 1.

Answer (score 0):

Algo to find index of duplicate

1. Create an array of string ( by spliting input by " ")
2. Iterate over array and build a map of each array element  to  list of its position in the map.
   3.Finally you have all info in map. For every entry  you have index it occur. If it is more than 1 then it is duplicate and u have index

Answer (score 0):

There are already a few correct answers here, let me just give a slightly more concise one to create the map, assuming that you are using Java 8:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < foxesList.size(); i++) {
    String fox = foxesList.get(i);
    map.computeIfAbsent(fox, f -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
```

Using [Map#computeIfAbsent](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) allows to have just one line for both the case where you already have a list in the map and where you don't.